# Enable TypeScript eslint rule for only a section of code

Tags: typescript-eslint

Is it possible to enable an eslint rule for only a section of code and have it disabled for all other code?

In our case, we have a class:

```
export class HeaderWidget extends AbstractWidget implements HeaderWidget.State {
  // tslint:disable-next-line:variable-name
  public readonly widget_type: WidgetType = WidgetType.Header;
  public text!: string;
  public image_data!: string;
  public image_data_alt!: string;
  public hide_on_mobile!: boolean;
...
}
```

We want to make sure that any properties added to this class are snake_case. I found the [naming-convention rule](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/naming-convention/) that I can enable with:

```
"@typescript-eslint/naming-convention": [
  "error",
  {
    "format": ["snake_case"],
    "selector": "classProperty"
  }
]
```

but that enables the rule for all the code in the project. I just want to enable for properties in that specific class (or even better would be anything that extends `AbstractWidget`). I see additional config options like `filter`, `custom` and `suffix` but the docs say they apply to the identifier which leads me to believe they can't be used to pick properties within a certain class.

So I'm looking for a way to configure a rule and have it disabled by default but then enable it for a specific section of code without having to add `/* eslint-disable naming-convention */` to every file.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found a solution that will work for us. In the `eslint.json` `overrides` section you can have multiple configs for different files. So adding:

```
{
      "files": ["*.model.ts"],
      "rules": {
        "@typescript-eslint/naming-convention": [
          "error",
          {
            "format": ["snake_case"],
            "selector": "classProperty"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

will work for us because the classes we want this rule to apply to will always be in `*.model.ts` and the only other things in there are `namespace` and `type` which this rule will not apply to.